# Reuse existing product IDs as primary key

Tags: mysql, database

I have some products, which has it's own ids and i'm designing MySQL DB and then I will import this data, there is much more than product table, but it doesn't matter now.

It's good idea to reuse existing product ids as primary key? So into the autoincerement ID column will be imported existing product ids, I never did that like I'm describing.

It is also worth to mention, that IDs are normal unsigned integer values and also that products are now only some rows in xls sheet.

Comment: It's the opposite of a good idea

Comment: I think the same, but I have to ask, how other coders look on this problem.

Comment: I delete this question, because i can get many negat. reputation points, even if I think that it's bad idea too.

Comment: I reused product ids as primary key and i don't have any problem, relations, ids, ... everything works as expected.

Comment: Cool, but please don't go recommending it as a strategy for others.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be great to keep the IDs as they are if you have any relationship build up upon those IDs, and for the new IDs that will be added just let them increment with the identity property.

To insert defined IDs on an identity column (auto-increment) use the following:

```
Set Identity_Insert [TableName] On
  -- --------------------------------------------
  youre insert query goes here
  -- --------------------------------------------
Set Identity_Insert [TableName] Off
```

Comment: The problem is, that I never did it before, but I don't see any problem, to reuse existing IDs as primary key. Why to maintain 2 IDs? When I don't reuse this IDs, so every relation will be on id column ( primary AI id ) and I will have to maintain product_id as internal product ID, but, if I reuse this IDs as primary ID, so every relation will be ok too and I will have only one product ID, I don't see any problem, but as I wrote, I don't think too that it's good idea and I never did it before, so i don't know :/

Comment: I don't see it as a "not good idea". You actually want to migrate data from one database table to another, if you wan't to keep the same structure/relationship, I would migrate the IDs too as they are, so no need for 2 columns, you have ID (auto-increment) column, stop the identity property so you can overwrite the values with the values from the old table, then put the identity property back on